# Issue with react router dom 6.2.2

Tags: reactjs

i have some problem with url. When i write url or when i refresh then i get 404. For example when i write: .../oferta then i get 404. NavLinks works fine. I don't know what i do wrong :)

error displayed is:404
Not Found
The resource requested could not be found on this server!

"react-router-dom": "6.2.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",

````
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Home from "./Home";
import Oferta from "./Oferta";
import Realizacje from "./Realizacje";
import Kontakt from "./Kontakt";
import ErrorPage from "./ErrorPage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ScrollToTop from "./ScrollToTop";
import ScrollButton from "./ScrollButton";
import CookieConsent from "react-cookie-consent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <Header />
      <section>
        <ScrollToTop>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/oferta" element={<Oferta />} />
            <Route path="/realizacje" element={<Realizacje />} />
            <Route path="/kontakt" element={<Kontakt />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </ScrollToTop>
        <ScrollButton />
      </section>
      <Footer />
      <CookieConsent
        location="bottom"
        buttonText="Zgoda"
        cookieName="myAwesomeCookieName2"
        style={{ background: "#2B373B", textShadow: "2px 2px black" }}
        buttonClasses="cat__link"
        buttonStyle={{
          color: "#4e503b",
          fontSize: "14px",
        }}
        expires={150}
      >
        Ta strona korzysta z plików cookies (ciasteczek) w celu poprawy odczuć
        użytkowników.
      </CookieConsent>
    </Router>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Can you clarify further? What error is displayed? Maybe show the `Oferta` component?

Answer (score 0):

If the component is showing when clicking the Link but it does not work when refreshing the URL, the problem could be your server configuration. You should configure your server to redirect 404 errors toward your index.html, so that React Router can handle the URL.